# how to schedule a task for every 5 minutes in windows command prompt?

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, command-prompt, windows-task-scheduler

I'm currently scheduling `.bat` files using Windows Task Scheduler. However, I want to do this using the Command Prompt's `schtasks` command. My batch file should run every five minutes and repeat its task every day.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I don't have much experience with .bat file (and maybe what I am about to write is nonsence), but I was wondering if a GOTO and a delay can resolve your problem.

```
:label
<do stuff>
SLEEP 300
GOTO label
```

LE:
Ok, I found something that might help you:

```
schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 5 /tn "TaskName" /tr \\scripts\whatever.bat
```

This line should do the trick. For more information you can visit https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772785(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Added something to my answer. I hope it helps

Comment: instead of sleep 300  one would use timeout 300 > nul

Comment: schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 5 /tn "TaskName" /tr \\scripts\whatever.bat , That works a treat! Any advice on how I can turn it off?

Comment: if you want to terminate the program that is run by the task, you can use: `schtasks /end /tn <taskname>`. If you want to remove the task altogether, you can use `schtasks /delete /tn <taskname>`. Note that the latter doesn't stop a running program started by this task